# SQL Dynamic Query String Breaks When Variable Contains Single Quote

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL query string that is like this:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
SET @sql = ' INSERT INTO ' + @tempTable1 + 
           ' SELECT 0 as Type1, 0 as Type2, ' + 
             '''' + @name + ''' as CompanyName ' + 
           ' FROM #tempTable2 tt2'
```

The query runs fine except for two names that happen to contain a single quote (ex: Pete's Corner). When either one of these names becomes part of the query it breaks the query string. I thought the easiest thing to do would be to replace the single quote like this replace(@name,'''','') but it doesn't work because I'm already in a string and so its affecting the rest of the statement. Altering the table itself is not an option unfortunately.

How can I replace or remove these single quotes?

Addition: I apologize, I did not include the part where @name is actually being populated from another database table by a join so setting the value of @name before the string is created I think would be difficult for me.

Comment: Why can't you do that at the time you populate @name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
 DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
SET @sql = ' INSERT INTO ' + @tempTable1 + 
       ' SELECT 0 as Type1, 0 as Type2, ' + ''''+
         replace( @name ,'''','''''')+''''+' as CompanyName  
       FROM #tempTable2 tt2'
```

Answer (score 6):

Why do you need to do this at all? You should be passing strong parameters to `sp_executesql` instead of munging all of your parameters into a single string and using `EXEC()`. [More info on that here](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql).

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX), @name NVARCHAR(32);

SET @name = 'Pete''s Corner';

SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tempTable1 +
  ' SELECT 0 as Type1, 0 as Type2, @name as CompanyName ' + 
  ' FROM #tempTable2 tt2';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@name NVARCHAR(32)', @name;
```

I presume the `@name` parameter actually gets populated from elsewhere, and if using proper parameterization you shouldn't have to deal with escaping the `'`.

Now I'm not quite sure what `@tempTable1` is supposed to represent, or if you can access `#tempTable2` from this scope, but whenever you find yourself running a replace that requires `''''` or `''''''` (or both), you should ask yourself if maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) system procedure. sp_executesql will allow you to call dynamic SQL with @name parameter instead of embedding it into the SQL.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max),
        @name varchar(50)
SET @name = 'qwe'''           
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tempTable1 +
           ' SELECT 0 as Type1, 0 as Type2, ' + 
           '@name as CompanyName ' + 
           'FROM #tempTable2 tt2'
--PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@name varchar(50)', @name
```